# Visual studio couldn't load file or assembly ,metroframework, Version=1.4.0.0 , Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Visual studio couldn't load file or assembly ,metroframework, Version=1.4.0.0 , Culture=neutral,publickeytoken='5f91a84759b584a' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.  (Exception from HRESULT:0X80131040)

This error occurs when i run my application every time

Comment: Usually these errors occur when you upgrade a project from one version of Visual Studios to another version of Visual Studios.  The upgrade process doesn't always work.  I can sometimes fix the issue by creating a new project.  Then compare the proj file of old and new project to see if versions on objects match.  Then edit old proj file to match new proj file.  If this doesn't work then create new project and add old items using ADD Existing Item.

Comment: Naah i just deleted the installed reference and reinstalled it again

Comment: I didn't say the reference.  I said the actually file.  Go to Solution Explorer and find file and delete. Then add.  Open the proj file with notepad and look for the reference and make sure it gets deleted.

Comment: Ìt didn't work because my solution explorer doesn't contains a file called metroframwork

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem

I just downloaded the required assembly from nuget

In my case i needed metroframework 1.4.0.0

The version is very important here

And every thing worked fine

Thqnk you for your time

I hope this post will help you with your PROBLEM

Yusuf naeem